# Javafx8 ProgressIndicator not showing in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, javafx-8, ubuntu-15.04, progress-indicator

I have developed an cross-platform app, which includes an javafx.stage.Popup object with javafx.scene.control.ProgressIndicator on it. It is showing on Windows, but not in Ubuntu(only percentage is showing), has anyone came across such problem

Comment: Please provide a [simple example](http://www.sscce.org/) demonstrating the problem.

Comment: popup = new Popup();
        popup.setWidth(ConfigClass.POPUP_WIDTH);
        popup.setHeight(ConfigClass.POPUP_HEIGHT);
popUpHBox = new AnchorPane();
  popUpHBox.setPrefWidth(ConfigClass.SCREENSHOT_POPUP_WIDTH);
  popUpHBox.setPrefHeight(ConfigClass.SCREENSHOT_POPUP_HEIGHT);
timer = new ProgressIndicator(timer_progress);
  timer.setPrefWidth(105);
  timer.setPrefHeight(88);
  
  timer.setLayoutX(105);
  timer.setLayoutY(56);
popUpHBox.getChildren().addAll(timer);
  popup.getContent().addAll(popUpHBox);
  popup.show(ViewClass.getStage());
  popup.setAutoHide(false);
  popup.setAutoFix(true);

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with giving progress-color property to progress indicator, linux just couldn't assign default background color to that component